# Can i use "==" in a http query string?

Tags: http, query-string

if I have a query string like:

```
?key1=val1&key2==val2
```

how it should be parsed?

like:

```
key   : key2= 
value : val2
```

or

```
key   : key2 
value : =val2
```

what would be the key and the value in this case?

Is this allowed to have == sequencies in query string?

And what about following query strings?

```
?key=val&=====
```

is that syntactically correct?

Thanks

Comment: I think in practice it's going to depend on what you want to use them for.

Comment: I never tried it but i think if you try to read the `key2` you will get `=vale2`.

Comment: I don't know about syntax rules, but I would definitely recommend against it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Judging from PHP implementation ([SAPI.treat_data](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/main/php_variables.c#356), used by both `parse_str` and in the internal params parsing), `=` symbol is always treated as the one separating the keys and values, and system-level separator (usually `&`) is used to separate the pairs. So in your first case, `key2` will be the key, and `=val2` will be the value. In your second case, the last series of `=====` will be just ignored, as there's no key to extract there.

Comment: I'm not sure, however, that all the query parser implementations follow the same routine. And it's up to implementation, as w3 only provides a recommendation of how to build a query string ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#form-content-type)).

Comment: If you need to include an "=" in the query string, then url encoding is intended specifically for that. You'd use `?key=val&%3D=%3D%3D` instead of `?key=val&====`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're likely to run into implementation-specific behavior if you try to use query strings like that, but at least as far as .NET's [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) goes, the breakdown would be:

```
key1=val1&key2==val2

key1 - val1
key2 - =val2


key=val&=====

key - val
    - ====     (key is blank, value is four =)
```

So this is basically equivalent to splitting the query string on `&` and then splitting each of those segments on the first `=`.

Comment: Same behavior in Java servlets (`HttpServletRequest.getParameter()`)